# WSO2 ESB Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, wso2, wiremock, wso2-esb

We've developed a Proxy Service into WSO2 ESB which is an orchestrator, and calls multiple services aggregating the response.

How can I test each single step (or mediator) of the proxy flow, and how the system reacts to each possible situation (e.g. Success, Failure, Slow response time...)?

We are trying to mock the behaviour of each service called by the proxy (with **Wiremock**), for each step, but we are not able to dynamically change the endpoints (or the ports) pointed by each call.

Example:

- Real service is listening on port **8280**
- Wiremock is listening on port **8281**
- We need to **dynamically change** the endpoint within the Proxy, to let it call the **Wiremock** service (8281) instead of the real one (8280)

If there are other ways to test, I'm happy to explore different solutions...

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to get your question correctly... can't you in Your proxy service you mention the endpoint url with port as 8281...??

Comment: Doing as you suggest, it would not be dynamically. I mean, should have 2 proxy definitions. What he is trying to change is the endpoint in code dynamically

Comment: Hi Javier,  Where exactly will we have to add your code... Class mediatior?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution to the problem.

Using the endpoints of the registry, you are able to get the resources from the registry, change them and update it.

For example you could do something like:

```java
AutomationContext esbContext = new AutomationContext("ESB", TestUserMode.SUPER_TENANT_ADMIN);
String esbSession = esbContext.login();

ResourceAdminServiceClient resourceClient = new ResourceAdminServiceClient(esbContext.getContextUrls().getBackEndUrl(),
            esbSession);

String endpoint = resourceClient.getTextContent("/_system/governance/endpoints/HelloService.xml")
            .replace(":8280", String.format(":%s", port));

resourceClient.updateTextContent("/_system/governance/endpoints/HelloService.xml", endpoint);
```